# Contravariant power functor is mutually right adjoint to itself

Tags: category-theory

I'm trying to prove that the contravariant power functor $P: Set^{op} \rightarrow Set$ is mutually right adjoint to itself.

First, I tried to define a natural isomorphism $Set(B, P(A)) \cong Set(A, P(B))$ for every $A,B \in Set$, but it doesn't seem to be a way to correspond the functions $f^{\#}:B \rightarrow P(A)$ with functions $f^{b}:A \rightarrow P(B)$; so I tried to define units $\eta: 1_C \Rightarrow PP$ and $\epsilon : 1_D \Rightarrow PP$, but It doesn't easy to manage the 'inverse of the inverse' in the naturality squares.

Do you have some idea?

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson It takes a function $f:A \rightarrow B$, and sends it to a function defined by $B' (\in PB) \mapsto f^{-1}B $

Comment: $P$ is a covariant functor $Set^{op}\rightarrow Set$, because a morphism $f:A\rightarrow B$ in $Set^{op}$ is a function $f:B\rightarrow A$ and $P$ send this function to $f^{-1}:PA\rightarrow PB$, so $P$ as a functor $Set^{op}\rightarrow Set$ is covariant. As for the question, notice that $PA\simeq 2^A=Set(A,2)$, where $2$ is the two element set $\{0,1\}$, so $$Set(B,PA)\simeq Set(B,2^A)\simeq Set(B\times A,2)$$

Comment: It is not correct that $P$ is right adjoint to itself. This cannot work since the domain and the codomain of $P$ are different. However, $P$ is right adjoint to $P^{op} : Set \to Set^{op}$.

Answer (score 2):

If $f : B \to P(A)$ is a map, we can define a map $d(f)  : A \to P(B)$ by
$$d(f) := \{b \in B : a \in f(b)\}.$$
It is easy to check $d(d(f))=f$, so that $f \mapsto d(f)$ is a bijection.

Naturality in $A$ is just a calculation with the definitions, and naturality in $B$ follows by symmetry: If $h : A' \to A$ is a map, thus inducing a map $h^{-1} : P(A) \to P(A')$, then
$$d(h^{-1} \circ f)(a')=\{b \in B : a' \in h^{-1}(f(b))\}=\{b \in B : h(a') \in f(b)\} = (d(f) \circ h)(a').$$

For a more conceptual explanation, notice that $\mathrm{Hom}(B,P(A))$ can be naturally identified with $P(B \times A)$ via $f \mapsto \{(b,a) : a \in f(b)\}$, and now use $B \times A \cong A \times B$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $(2^A)^B \cong 2^{A\times B} \cong (2^B)^A$.